# JTree - JLabel update

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtree

The labels of some nodes of a JTree represent counter which increase in length after some counting. That results in an abbreviation (...). Imagine you have a tree where every node could change it's label size at any point in time.

The tree is repainted (tree.repaint()) every 100ms in a separate Thread to keep track of changing icons and changing labels which are the result of tracked events and progress in time. I tried an approach where I replaced the repaint() method with a nodeChanged() call on every tree node. The tree starts flickering.

What do I need to do, in order to update those node labels according to their new length?
I am already extending a DefaultTreeCellRenderer.

```
 public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node;
    Object                 nodeValue;
    TestComponent          currentComponent;

    super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);

    node      = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
    nodeValue = node.getUserObject();


    if(nodeValue instanceof TestComponent) {
        currentComponent = (TestComponent) nodeValue;
        setText(currentComponent.getLabel());

    }       
    return this;
}
```

What should I do within that CellRenderer inorder to "fix" the problem with "setText"?

Comment: What do I need to do ----> [Swing and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) similair concept for `JComboBox`, `JList`, `JTable` and `JTree`,

Comment: I'm not judge here, maybe you are right, and you have got poor answers (I'm never to checked users profiles), but I'm post link to Renderers concept, search here renderer & PreferredSize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The tree is repainted (tree.repaint()) every 100ms in a separate Thread, to keep track of changing icons and changing labels which are the result of tracked events and progress in time

Wrong, the `TreeModel` should fire events, based on the tracked events, and the `JTree` will automatically update. Those changes should of course happen on the EDT, and not on a separate `Thread`.

And unfortunately, the size of the `JTree` (and hence the size of the labels contained in it) will be limited by the parent container in which the `JTree` is contained. And this size will not automatically grow when the size of your `JTree` grows.

Comment: If you put the JTree in a JScrollPane, the JTree will be sized to its preferredSize.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet indeed but that does not solve the visibility problem as you have to scroll horizontally which is as easy as enlarging the parent container so that the labels are no longer cut-off. Another option is to opt for a multiline text area and hoping you have enough vertical space

Comment: there is actually enough room for my purpose, but the labels get cut off anyways when increasing in length. since data and gui are strictly seperated, there is no way to fire an event without and additional update thread....

Comment: "Programs whose GUI must be updated as the result of non-AWT events: For example, suppose a server program can get requests from other programs that might be running on different machines. These requests can come at any time, and they result in one of the server's methods being invoked in some possibly unknown thread. How can that method update the GUI? By executing the GUI update code in the event-dispatching thread."